# my app show error "Rate limit exceeded"

Tags: php, twitter, error-handling, twitter-oauth

I used the below code for connecting twitter account into my website:

```
     $twitteroauth = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $_SESSION['TWITTER_token'], $_SESSION['TWITTER_token_secret']);
        $user_info = $twitteroauth->get('account/verify_credentials');
        $user_info_tw = json_decode( json_encode($user_info), true);  
        echo "<pre>";print_r($user_info_tw);echo "</pre>";
            if(!empty($user_info_tw['errors'])){    echo "<br><br><br>";
                foreach($user_info_tw['errors'] AS $error){
                    echo    $error['message'];
                }
            }else{
                echo $_SESSION['user_info_tw']=$user_info_tw['id'];
                echo $_SESSION['user_screen_name_tw']=$user_info_tw['screen_name'];   

            }
```

it was working fine but from Friday onward my app show error

"Rate limit exceeded"

Whereas i didn't used my app( not log in or post) but it shows error continuously .How can i solve this.?

Comment: If you check how many requests you can make do you have any? https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/application/rate_limit_status

Comment: @chris85 but i did't used from past 4 days.then why this showing error.and how can i extend ratelimit.?

Comment: i used for checking request :$tweets = $twitteroauth->get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/application/rate_limit_status.json?resources=help,users,search,statuses');    response is:[users] => stdClass Object    (  [/users/show/:id] => stdClass Object  ( [limit] => 180
[remaining] => 180        [reset] => 1426145280
                        )

                    [/users/search] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [limit] => 180
                            [remaining] => 180
                            [reset] => 1426145280
                        )

Comment: if any one have solution please help me asap bcz i am going to live my app